# How can I automatically alert my php/mysql web app that a PayPal transaction has gone through?

Tags: php, mysql, paypal

I have a client who will be selling access to an online service on their website. They would like to integrate a PayPal Buy Now button into the site... no problems there. However, they want their customers to have instant access to the online service that they are selling as soon as the payment is processed. That seems reasonable to me... the problem is that I can't seem to find a way to automate that. So my question is really this:

**How can I automatically alert my php/mysql web app that a PayPal transaction has gone through?**

All I would really need is like a callback process that triggers a php script to updates the customer's record in the database... right? Seems simple to me. But I can't seem to find a way to do it! Anyway, if you've accomplished anything similar with PayPal, I'd be grateful for your advice!

Comment: I have never done it but it is doable for sure because I see it all the time all over.

Comment: The client just mentioned that he's not married to PayPal... he's open to exploring other payment gateways, such as Google Checkout. Does anyone have any experience with other platforms? Any preference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Instant Payment Notification](https://www.paypal.com/ipn).

Comment: Wow... the speed of Stack Overflow never ceases to amaze me. Anyway, I think this is what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to send in a variable to paypal (item_number) that they will return to a page that you specify in your post to them (return - success and cancel_return - cancel).  They will send you back whether the transaction was successful or not and then with your variable you can make a call to your db to update the record in your database based upon the result of the transaction.  In the return page you can also send some sort of notification to the client of the success or failure of the payment process and clean up after a canceled transaction.

Comment: Right... I think that's what's happening with the Instant Payment Notification mentioned above. I'm still looking for a step-by-step on how to do it though!

Answer (score 0):

PayPal maintains an extensive knowledge base on how to integrate their services with your web app. In think that is a good first starting point. See [www.x.com](http://www.x.com)